# doing post webrequest and receiving error while reading Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

i am trying to do post request in asp.net4.0 c#. but i am receiving error while reading response.

Error:
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

```
  public static string PostWithResponse(string PostUrl, string DataUrl, string PostContentType, bool isTimeOut, int ResponseTimeOut)            
  {
        string returnPostResponse = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest PostRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PostUrl);
        PostRequest.ContentType = PostContentType;
        PostRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataUrl);
        Stream os = null;
        try
        {
            PostRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            os = PostRequest.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            if (isTimeOut)
            {
                PostRequest.Timeout = ResponseTimeOut;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
        finally
        {
            if (os != null)
            {
                os.Close();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse PostResponse = (HttpWebResponse)PostRequest.GetResponse();
            if (PostResponse == null)
            {
                //
            }
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PostResponse.GetResponseStream());
            returnPostResponse = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error Found Here
        }
        return returnPostResponse;
  }
```

Comment: Could be a number of things. Have you tried using a proxy tool to see the request? Try WireShark.

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: You need to ensure the request is leaving your application and that something is being returned to your application. Using a tool such as WireShark will show all communications and will hopefully identify your issue or at least eliminate problems. What you've posted above isn't enough information for someone to realistically be able to help you.

Comment: do i need to set               PostRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: No - I assume you've not got a proxy server which requires authentication?